# Flutter: Turn off screen when phone close to face

Tags: flutter, sensors

I'm doing calling feature in Flutter and I need to know whether user wants to listen with earpeace and turn off the screen, set audio output to earpeace. Is there a sensor to know if phone is close to face/ear to turn off the screen ?

Comment: Use `all_sensors` package https://pub.dev/packages/all_sensors/install to get the value of proximity sensor which tells about how close the phone is to face or anything (returns true and false only). Now you get the value now you can make phone lock using `wakelock` package https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock/install

Comment: Thanks @ChiragBargoojar, I couldn't compile with all_sensors, now I'm using proximity_sensor:

Comment: You need to up your minSDKVersion to 19 inside `app/build.gradle` because `all_sensor` package requires minSDKVersion of 19

Comment: Mine is already 21 minSDK

Comment: This is the example using `all_sensors` package. https://pub.dev/packages/all_sensors/example

Comment: Adding to @ChiragBargoojar answer's, now all_sensors package handle turn off/on of the screen

Answer (score 2):

I was able to know with this plugin [proximity_sensor](https://pub.dev/packages/proximity_sensor)

Answer (score 0):

The only package that worked and actually turned off the screen on proximity is the [flutter_incall package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_incall) like this:

```
IncallManager().turnScreenOff();
IncallManager().turnScreenOn();
```

The problem is that this package is so old and missing so many modern flutter updates like null-safety and Android embedding 2.0.

I tried using wakelock as many suggested, but the functionality is different from what I am looking for.